On the Boeing 737 ND display what does terrain value indicate?
On the Boeing 737 ND display what does terrain value indicate? (e.g. Terr 0016 0032)

On the 777 FCOM, it is written

Upper value of the TERR thing is altitude of the highest object in the selected range of the map
Lower value is the altitude of the lowest object in the selected range of the map

Both of these values are in feet and for example 020 is 2000 feet, 014 is 1400 feet. When any number is in red, or if the terrain is red, it means it is at or above your current altitude.
